# Use return and print in the same function in Python

Tags: python

I hope my question does not sound too silly - but is it good programming practice to use return and print statement one after the other in the same function in Python?

e.g.

```
def test():
    ...
    if retval < 0:
            errval = "Error in reading value"
            print errval
            return errval
```

'errval' is being used by another function, and it also has to be printed.
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It might be better practice to print it outside of the function. Or, if this is actually and error, maybe you should `raise` an exception with a descriptive name instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general advice:

- Ideally, the bulk of your program consists of functions (or methods) that
  return data, mutate the state of `self` (for object-oriented code), or raise
  exceptions. In that world, printing is rarely, if ever, done.
- Surrounding that **data-oriented core**, your program might have various needs to
  print. But even there, I suggest that you never print directly. Instead,
  write a printing function. That way, as your program grows more complex,
  you'll be able to manage printing behavior in a more consistent way.
- Regarding your specific question ... it depends. How is this function being
  used, what is its place within the larger program, what is the expected
  behavior of that program, and so forth? But in general, I suspect that I
  would not write a function that prints an error message and then returns it.
  If I saw that in a colleague's code, it would catch my eye and I would think
  hard about whether there is a better design for the problem at hand.
- As always, have the good sense to ignore general advice when the specifics of
  a situation demand it.